# Regular Expression - Pure url

Tags: ruby, regex

I improve url sort service with rails. I want to get only the domain name, for example: www.hudu.com or http://www.hudu.org or http://hudu.net result => 'hudu'

Comment: Use URI module for that: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: How are you going to handle domains with compound TLDs such as ones containing a country-code like `www.foo.com.au`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use regex pattern `^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\.` with `i` modifier and read first capture group.

```
m = string.match(/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([^.]+)\./i).captures
puts m[0]
```

Test it **[here](http://ideone.com/9V3cmQ)**.

Comment: What does your regex do with a URL that contains username and password components?

Comment: @muistooshort - You are welcome to post such question. I see no indication in OP's question that such syntax should be considered.